# Please provide your full input file and your full output file (and error message if there is one)

Tags: discussion, faq, policies

If your question is related to a calculation that didn't work, please provide your input and output files in a `code` block. We have a 30,000 character limit, which is enough for almost all cases, and otherwise we have a GitHub repository that contains input and output files (and data files) for MMSE posts, more details about the GitHub repository are given here: [Why do we not allow links to Google Drive files?](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/393/5)

Please see the following examples:

- [Why does CCSD work, but not CCSD(T), after reading an FCIDUMP in PySCF?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10277/5)
- [PySCF: How to do CCSD calculations from an FCIDUMP file in HDF5 format?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10349/5)
- [Is PySCF able to print checkpoint files during a CISD calculation?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10444/5)